# Detect drive mount event in c#

Tags: c#, winapi, filesystems, mount, drive

How to catch an event when a new drive is added to My Computer and preferably and when new mount point for some drive is created on a NTFS drive?

---

I figued out this but it doesn't work  on mounted folders:

```
 _eventWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent");

 _eventWatcher.EventArrived += (o, args) => 
     {switch(args.NewEvent["EventType"].ToString()[0])
         {
             case '2':
                 //mount
                 Debug.WriteLine(args.NewEvent["DriveName"]);
                 break;
             case '3':
                 //unmount
                 break;
         }
     };

 _eventWatcher.Start();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019065/monitoring-drives-with-wmi

Comment: With Windows API you should process WM_DEVICECHANGE message. Don't know how to handle it in C#, though.

Comment: Is there something like this just for mounted folders on NTFS drives?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a form, you can override its WndProc method to catch WM_DEVICECHANGE messages as Eugene mentioned:

```
private const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x219;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(m);

    if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
    {
        // Check m.wParam to see exactly what happened
    }
}
```

Comment: I will probably need to port my code to windows service some time later so this solution won't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you want to do it in a Windows Service you must check this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Windows_Services.aspx?msg=2900262