# Detect network drive mount wmi

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, wmi, drive

How to detect network drive mount event using wmi ? I'm mainly interested i something like Win32_VolumeChangeEvent just for network drives.

```
 _eventWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent");

 _eventWatcher.EventArrived += (o, args) => 
     {switch(args.NewEvent["EventType"].ToString()[0])
         {
             case '2':
                 //mount
                 Debug.WriteLine(args.NewEvent["DriveName"]);
                 break;
             case '3':
                 //unmount
                 break;
         }
     };

 _eventWatcher.Start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query (I use Powershell for rapid test but you can easily transform to C#)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM __instanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' AND TargetInstance.DriveType=4"

Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -Action {$global:a=$Args[0];$global:b=$Args[1];write-host "done" }

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location  Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------  -------
14              f2c5223d-3ae... NotStarted False                     $global:a=$Args[0];$gl...


PS C:\> net use
Les nouvelles connexions seront mémorisées.

La liste est vide.

PS C:\> net use o: \\jpbhpp2\c$
La commande s'est terminée correctement.

PS C:\> done


PS C:\> $a


Scope     : System.Management.ManagementScope
Query     : System.Management.EventQuery
Options   : System.Management.EventWatcherOptions
Site      :
Container :



PS C:\> $b

NewEvent                                                    Context
--------                                                    -------
System.Management.ManagementBaseObject                      {}


PS C:\> $b.NewEvent


__GENUS             : 2
__CLASS             : __InstanceCreationEvent
__SUPERCLASS        : __InstanceOperationEvent
__DYNASTY           : __SystemClass
__RELPATH           :
__PROPERTY_COUNT    : 3
__DERIVATION        : {__InstanceOperationEvent, __Event, __IndicationRelated, __SystemClass}
__SERVER            : WM2008R2ENT
__NAMESPACE         : //./root/CIMV2
__PATH              :
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR :
TargetInstance      : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
TIME_CREATED        : 129670237461553750



PS C:\> $b.NewEvent.TargetInstance


__GENUS                      : 2
__CLASS                      : Win32_LogicalDisk
__SUPERCLASS                 : CIM_LogicalDisk
__DYNASTY                    : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                    : Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="O:"
__PROPERTY_COUNT             : 40
__DERIVATION                 : {CIM_LogicalDisk, CIM_StorageExtent, CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement...}
__SERVER                     : WM2008R2ENT
__NAMESPACE                  : root\CIMV2
__PATH                       : \\WM2008R2ENT\root\CIMV2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="O:"
Access                       : 0
Availability                 :
BlockSize                    :
Caption                      : O:
Compressed                   : False
ConfigManagerErrorCode       :
ConfigManagerUserConfig      :
CreationClassName            : Win32_LogicalDisk
Description                  : Connexion réseau
DeviceID                     : O:
DriveType                    : 4
ErrorCleared                 :
ErrorDescription             :
ErrorMethodology             :
FileSystem                   : NTFS
FreeSpace                    : 36223737856
InstallDate                  :
LastErrorCode                :
MaximumComponentLength       : 255
MediaType                    : 0
Name                         : O:
NumberOfBlocks               :
PNPDeviceID                  :
PowerManagementCapabilities  :
PowerManagementSupported     :
ProviderName                 : \\jpbhpp2\c$
Purpose                      :
QuotasDisabled               : True
QuotasIncomplete             : False
QuotasRebuilding             : False
Size                         : 500000878592
Status                       :
StatusInfo                   :
SupportsDiskQuotas           : True
SupportsFileBasedCompression : True
SystemCreationClassName      : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                   : WM2008R2ENT
VolumeDirty                  :
VolumeName                   :
VolumeSerialNumber           : 96B00597
```

Answer (score 1):

For network share monitoring you can use RegistryKeyChangeEvent.

1. RegistryKeyChangeEvent is located in root\default. (Not root\CIMV2 which is used by .net as default)
2. Mount point information is stored in registry in: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network. But, RegistryKeyChangeEvent can't monitor HKEY_CURRENT_USER (bummer). Thus, you'll have to access it by: HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Network (where S-1-5-18 is your user's SID).
3. To determine your user's SID check the followind registry path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList.

The final code should be something like this:

```
Dim m As New ManagementEventWatcher("root\default", "SELECT * FROM RegistryKeyChangeEvent WHERE Hive=""HKEY_USERS"" AND KeyPath=""<YOUR USER SID HERE>\\Network""") 
AddHandler m.EventArrived, AddressOf <YOUR HANDLER FUNCTION>
m.Start()
```

This code will call the handler function every time the user mounts **or dismounts** a network share.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for any VolumeChangeEvent and then just check if the drive is a network drive:

```
DriveInfo info = new DriveInfo(driveLetter);
if(info.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
    //DoSomething
```

Comment: It seems that it isn't catching it. I don't know why.

Comment: How are you trying to capture it?

Comment: Quick search: your code does not detect network drives (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188876/detect-drive-mount-event-in-c-sharp). May try this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx.

Comment: I need to use this in windows service in some time so I would prefer wmi.

Comment: The see here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Windows_Services.aspx?msg=2900262 or do it the way I did: Just add an invisible window to the service.