# WMI query on VolumeChangeEvent for SD card insertion into SD card reader not working

Tags: .net, wmi-query

I'm developing an application where I would like to process data automatically from an SD card when it's inserted in an SD card reader. The SD card reader is inserted into the computer and assigned the E: and F: drives and are greyed out when there's no SD card inserted. I've been trying to use an WMI query based on Win32__VolumeChangeEvent or Win32__DeviceChangeEvent, but without success. The error I get for "select * from Win32_VolumeChangeEvent" is invalid class, and "select * from Win32_DeviceChangeEvent" doesn't show me status updates when I insert an SD card into the SD card reader, only for the insertion and removal of the SD card reader itself.

A class that I've been using to experiment is :

```
 namespace eventTest
{
    class WMIReceiveEvent
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WMIReceiveEvent receiveEvent = new WMIReceiveEvent();
            Console.Read();
        }

        public WMIReceiveEvent()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
                scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
                WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("select * from Win32_DeviceChangeEvent");
                ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an event...");

                watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(HandleEvent);

                // Start listening for events
                watcher.Start();
            }
            catch (ManagementException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while trying to receive an event: " + err.Message);
            }
        }

        private void HandleEvent(object sender,
            EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.NewEvent.GetPropertyValue("EventType"));
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide we with a query that I can use to monitor the arrival of the SD card in Windows or point me out why Win32_VolumeChangeEvent isn't accepted as a valid class and if fixed how it can be used to monitor the arrival of the actual SD card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is an working solution for my problem, where I am notified when a SD card enters a USB connected SD card reader. The query is

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and TargetInstance.Size > 0 AND TargetInstance.Description = "Removable disk"
```

which selects all operations on logical disks where the size is > 0 and where it concerns a removable drive. It is possible to further differentiate between the kind of operation (insert and removal) and to retrieve the drive letter of the inserted SD card. (For examples see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019065/monitoring-drives-with-wmi) )

EDIT: the event that triggers on insertion seems to be an "__InstanceModificationEvent" which can be used instead of the __InstanceOperationEvent (__InstanceModificationEvent is a childclass of __InstanceOperationEvent), in which case the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and TargetInstance.Size > 0 AND TargetInstance.Description = "Removable disk"
```

Complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Threading;


namespace eventTest
{
    class WMIReceiveEvent
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WMIReceiveEvent receiveEvent = new WMIReceiveEvent();
            Console.Read();
        }

        public WMIReceiveEvent()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
                scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
                WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and TargetInstance.Size > 0 AND TargetInstance.Description = \"Removable disk\"");
                ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an event...");

                watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(HandleEvent);

                // Start listening for events
                watcher.Start();
            }
            catch (ManagementException err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while trying to receive an event: " + err.Message);
            }
        }

        private void HandleEvent(object sender,
            EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //ManagementBaseObject baseObject = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent;

           // if (baseObject.ClassPath.ClassName.Equals("__InstanceCreationEvent"))
                Console.WriteLine("A drive was connected");
            //else if (baseObject.ClassPath.ClassName.Equals("__InstanceDeletionEvent"))
                //Console.WriteLine("A drive was removed");
        }
    }
}
```